# create altered time record based on existing value

Tags: php, time

How do you take an existing 'date and time' value and convert it to the same date but a specified time?

For example, $time="2017-09-01 13:18:00" -> how to do you convert to "2017-09-01 23:59:59"? It must keep the date but change the time to 23:59:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this by explode and simple concatenation

```
  <?php
    $time="2017-09-01 13:18:00";
    $date = explode(" ", $time)[0];
    echo $date." 23:59:59";
  ?>
```

Live demo :  https://eval.in/853822

Update

I think you need this

```
 <?php
    $date = new DateTime('2017-09-01 13:18:00');
    $date->setTime(23, 59,59);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/853857

Comment: I need the result to be an intact datetime for further calculating

Comment: Use like this : `new Datetime($date." 23:59:59");`  check this : https://eval.in/853834

Comment: Still not making sense for me... <?php
$date ="2017-10-03";
$newtime = new Datetime($date." 23:59:59");
echo $newtime;
?>
//errors out

Comment: You should it `print_r($newtime)` not echo .

Comment: It's a object , check my demo in comment above

Comment: I actually need to continue using the value in time calculations so I need to assign it to a variable but it gives this error: "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string" when doing it your way with the "explode"

Comment: is there not a simpler way? perhaps just to edit the value? we are starting with a date/time and just need to alter the time of it

Comment: Can you provide full detail ? Or any live demo example ?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-09-01 13:18:00');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT10H30S'));
```

Comment: or more user-friendly:                                                                              `$date = new DateTime('2017-09-01 13:18:00');
$date->modify('+ 10 hour 41 minutes 59 sec');`